# Why is this SQL query failing?

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the following SQL:

```
SELECT mov
FROM movie
WHERE mov IN
    (
        SELECT mov
        FROM movie_star
        GROUP BY(mov)
        HAVING count(star) > 6
    )
INNER JOIN movie_star
ON movie_star.mov = movie.mov;
```

I am getting the following error when this query is executed:

> .ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'inner join movie_star on movie_star.mov =
>   movie.mov' at line 3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `JOIN` has to go before the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT movie.mov
FROM movie
INNER JOIN movie_star ON movie_star.mov = movie.mov
WHERE mov IN (SELECT mov FROM movie_star GROUP BY mov HAVING COUNT(star) > 6);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's the same query cleaned up a little:

```
select mov
from movie
where
    mov in (select mov from movie_star group by(mov) having count(star) > 6)
inner join movie_star on movie_star.mov = movie.mov
```

You have a syntax error because an `inner join` appears after your `where` clause, when it should appear immediately after the `from` clause instead.

Try this instead:

```
select mov
from movie
inner join movie_star on movie_star.mov = movie.mov
group by mov
having count(*) > 6
```

Comment: your version is the cleanest and self-resolved without use of the IN sub-select others have left in.

Comment: I agree, much better to do it without the sub-select, but the question did ask why it wasn't working, hence the other answers not going on to do it differently.  Good that someone did though.

Answer (score 1):

You've got the inner join in the wrong place. Not sure I see the need for the inner join at all when you're only selecting the `movie.mov` column and the IN clause already guarantees that there are matching rows in `movie_star`.

```
select mov 
    from movie
        inner join movie_star 
            on movie_star.mov = movie.mov
    where mov in (select mov 
                      from movie_star 
                      group by(mov) 
                      having count(star)>6);
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to join before you can use the where clause:

```
select mov from movie
inner join movie_star on movie_star.mov = movie.mov
where mov in
(select mov from movie_star group by(mov) having count(star)>6)
```